# Some citations from my (Mendeley exported) bibtex library do not work

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, citing

I work with a bibtex library that I exported from Mendeley.
It all works well, except for some of the citations and I can't figure out why. These citations are simply not recognised in the main Overleaf file, even though they exist in the .bib file. I don't see anything that could be different with these citations. Another strange thing is that in most of these cases, they worked worked at first and then suddenly stopped (after an update, also the reference name changed). I dont see an error in the log.

[image: reference in .bib file]
[image: in the verleaf file it doesnt find the reference (a different paper by the same author shows)]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please type your examples, instead of posting a picture.

Comment: Did you check the .blg log or just the regular .log? In addition to posting a real version of the entries we can copy and paste, please post a minimal document that is enough to reproduce the issue. See [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that),

Comment: I see that your reference does not pop up in the editor, but have you tried to use it anyway? Like writing `\cite{Callaghan2013}` in your file? If this work, the problem is with the editor and not with the LaTeX system.

Comment: we can't debug an image, the image does not even show the full entry. Make a bib file with the bad entries, and a small but complete document using that

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your reactions, sorry for my late reply (I was on holiday).

I think all your thoughts coming my way must have woken up Overleaf, as suddenly the citations started working (I changed nothing!). Some of them completely and other by just typing them out as Rmano suggested (which also didn't work before). It's a mystery to me!
Suzanne